# RSpec mock a class with nested attributes

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, rspec

I'm very new to Ruby and RSpec and I'm having trouble trying to mock a chain of attributes inside of a class:

```
client.conversations.configuration.update(sid: user.sid)
```

I have already mocked the client like so:

```
let(:client) { class_double(Service::ClientFactory) }
```

However, this is what I've tried and failed using the `receive` method, which doesn't work.

```
  allow(client).to receive(conversations.configuration.update).and_return("123123123")
```

How can I do this correctly?
Thank you!

Comment: You could use [stub_chain](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/2-0/docs/stubs/stub-a-chain-of-methods) for this, but it's probably better to just not stub it at all ... Why _are_ you trying to stub this?

Comment: *Why* is a great question. I assume you have tested `client.conversations`, `conversations.configuration` and `configuration.update` individually (if you haven't you should) so is there really a need to test this at all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to use [`receive_message_chain`](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/docs/working-with-legacy-code/message-chains):

```
allow(
  client
).to receive_message_chain(:conversations, :configuration, update: "123123123")
```

But please have a look at the section on that page too:

> Warning:
>
> Chains can be arbitrarily long, which makes it quite painless to violate the Law of Demeter
> in violent ways, so you should consider any use of receive_message_chain a code smell. [...]

Comment: Thank you, I will have that in consideration 